# The statement "if this OR that do X" won't work in PHP

Tags: php, if-statement

I'm trying to show some information on screen only if a certain field is not null or if it doesn't say the word "null".
I'm working with a PHP script.

For some reason I have a database that has some values set as null as a string, instead as a real `NULL` value. As there are many items and I still don't know what causes to set the field as "null" instead of `NULL`, it's going to be easier to just set that with an if statement for the time being.

But for some reason, this is not working:

```
if ($row['cronograma'] != NULL || $row['cronograma'] != 'null') {
echo 'This is my reply';
}
```

If the field is actually `NULL`, the echo won't show up. If the field has the string null in it it does show up.

Please note that the fields in question are either NULL or has the "null" string without any spaces.

Comment: Think you're after and here. If it's not null AND doesn't equal the string "null", show it.

Comment: Oh my! You're right (I'm failing logic 101 here). Thank for your comment. If you post it as a reply, I'll accept it. THANKS!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're after `and` rather than `or`. That is, if the value is not `null` AND is not the string `"null"`:

```
if ($row['cronograma'] != NULL && $row['cronograma'] != 'null') {
//                             ^^
```

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for "and" rather than "or" logic. Also, you should always use strict equality (triple equals) when comparing with NULL to prevent weird edge cases from popping up:

```
if ($row['cronograma'] !== NULL && $row['cronograma'] !== 'null') {
    echo 'This is my reply';
}
```